# Selenium: any more ideas what to do when everything fails but Sleep?

Tags: selenium, c#

So... I have no idea why (well, probably Javascript) but here are the different issues with the code below.

1. With a visibility/enabled wait, Selenium executes the Click() but it doesn't do anything on the page (scripts not yet loaded?). Or sometimes `ShouldBeClickable()` even returns a `StaleElementException` because the page is still loading.
2. With a `JQuery.Active == 0` wait, I get the same result: it returns True immediately.
3. With a hard coded wait of 1 second, the page acts correctly.

**What other options do I have?**

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser.Driver;

        while (true)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loop!");
            if (sw.Elapsed.Seconds > 15) throw new Exception("Timeout");
            if ((bool)js.ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"))
            {
                // Final wait while initializing new elements
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Done!");
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                break;
            }
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        btnNext.ShouldBeClickable();
        btnNext.Click();
```

Comment: Which browser are you having the issues with?

Comment: Chrome! I just ran the same test on Firefox and it works there. The overall test looks slower, maybe Chrome is loading too quick? :)

Comment: (1) Can you detect when page is loaded fully by waiting for some element which is displayed AFTER page is loaded? (2) How you locate btnNext? (3) Use explicit waits consistently. Do not mix implicit and explicit waits.

Comment: (1) That's the thing... It's a very simple page visually (a resume and two buttons) so Selenium thinks it's loaded but not the scripts. I found that two scripts are active upon documentLoaded for about 150ms. So waiting 200ms also works. (2) By.ID

Comment: When you open the page source (HTML) and search the **script** tags which do you see?  **jquery**, **angular**, or **protractor**?

Comment: There are several "bundles" linked in the file, which contain at least Modernizr, JQuery and Angular. Like so: <script src="/App/bundles/js-ondocumentready?v=tZR8huQlxnn_gQWR5-sTWJz70hVvPMtLwo5w-ZL30kE1"></script>

Comment: Found a solution, in theory at least.

Comment: @FDM Honestly, this is the type of thing I would report to my developers. Things being loaded out of sequence can cause issues and the fix should be relatively easy if everyone has done their job correctly. Just because you CAN fix it on your end doesn't mean you SHOULD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the actual issue was that a visible button was clicked, before the javascript handler for it was loaded.

Theoretical solution (still have to test it properly) is this:
**use Fiddlercore to listen for all HTTP(S) requests and responses**. If I know the required resource for the button action, I can simply check for every succesfull response if it matches the resource path. Once it's been returned with a proper status code (200) I can continue clicking.

Comment: You could try utilizing the Document.readyState property on the page.  Using the javascript executor to get it's current value, waiting until it's either interactive or complete, which should help inform you when the page's async scripts have finished doing their thing.  (This can sometimes not be a reliable solution depending on the specific app under test, but is a solution I like to include alongside others)

Comment: @JulianCleary doesn't Selenium already wait for a DOM in this state?

Comment: Selenium doesn't use the readyState property last I checked.  Though that could be specific to the implementation being used.

Comment: See Slanec's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122864/selenium-wait-until-document-is-ready